# Android http post

Tags: android, post

Приветствую, как правильно сформировать post запрос такого вида.

```
"extra_data" =     {
       expired = 0;
   };
   profile =     {
       city = city;
       name = "Dima";
       sex = male;
       totalFriens = 15;
   };
   provider = VK;
   token = ce13b8bd7935a3d967143ab8845fcf51d647885e79d406f433d3318a42a9c88;
   uid = 10588406;
```

Comment: что тут чем является? Боди? Параметры? Куки?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так

```
public static void post(String url, String param ) throws Exception{
  String charset = "UTF-8"; 
  URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
  connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.
  connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=" + charset);

  try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
    output.write(param.getBytes(charset));
  }

  InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
}
```